Exponential Generating Function Trees with a certain number of children
Exponential Generating Function for certain trees
I read the response to the SE post above and have a question. Let $T$ be the species of rooted unordered trees with 2 children (binary trees), then $T = X(1 + T^2/2!)$ according to the hint. However, my question is, if $X$ represents the species picking out the root node in the tree, why do we need to divide the $T^2$ term by $2!$, which presumably removes the ordering of the two children nodes. More specifically, I think my question relates to the definition of the product of species as well as disjoint unions.
In Combinatorial Species and Tree-like Structures by Francois Bergeron, Gilbert Labelle and Pierre Leroux, a species product is defined as follows: for any finite set $U$, $$(F \cdot G)[U] = \sum_{U_1 \sqcup U_2 = U}F[U_1] \times G[U_2],$$ the disjoint sum being taken over all decompositions $(U_1, U_2)$ of $U$.
Then, taking $U = [3] = \{1, 2, 3\}$, are $(U_1, U_2) = (\{1, 3\}, \{2\})$ and $(U_1, U_2) = (\{2\}, \{1, 3\})$ distinct disjoint partitions of $U$? In particular, do we go through both of these disjoint unions in the summation over the disjoint partitions of $U$?

Yes, ({1,3},{{2}) and ({2},{1,3}) are considered distinct partitions, and that is the reason you need to divide by $2!$.
